# Extracting k/v pair from nested json based upon other known k/v pair

Tags: python, json, path

I do receive a JSON file which I am able to handle for most part in Python. However, a part of the file is containing data structured like the example below.

```
{
    "panObjectAggregateResultList": [
      {"rownumber": 1,"field": "detector","id": "331","description": "running jobs","count": 4,"quantile": null,"quantile_class": null},
      {"rownumber": 2,"field": "detector","id": "51","description": "closed lines","count": 29,"quantile": null,"quantile_class": null},
      {"rownumber": 3,"field": "detector","id": "334","description": "pids","count": 2,"quantile": null,"quantile_class": null}
    ]
}
```

As an example, I need to to obtain the value count for "running jobs", however, the only "value" I have to search with through the file in Python is "running jobs".

What I try to achieve is getting (A) the value from count based upon "description": "running jobs" or (B) the JSON path based upon "description": "running jobs" so I can get the value for count manually.

I have been looking into [JSONPath RW](https://github.com/kennknowles/python-jsonpath-rw) and some other options, however up until now no clear solution found to do this in a sane way.

the issue is, I cannot change the JSON in the source to make this more easy as I do not own the REST API and the JSON file can be relativly big so I am looking for a sane and performing way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try jsonpath-ng `pip install jsonpath-ng`.

```
from jsonpath_ng.ext import parse

null = None
json_data = {
    "panObjectAggregateResultList": [
        {"rownumber": 1,"field": "detector","id": "331","description": "running jobs","count": 4,"quantile": null,"quantile_class": null},
        {"rownumber": 2,"field": "detector","id": "51","description": "closed lines","count": 29,"quantile": null,"quantile_class": null},
        {"rownumber": 3,"field": "detector","id": "334","description": "pids","count": 2,"quantile": null,"quantile_class": null}
    ]
}

f = parse(f"$..panObjectAggregateResultList[?(@..description=='running jobs')]").find(json_data)
print(f[0].value['count'])
```

Comment: Superb... with some small edits left and right I have it working based upon the example provided by @frans